# Calculating Exponential Moving Average in Python

Tags: python, mathematics

I'm in the process of creating a forex trading algorithm and wanted to try my shot at calculating EMA (Exponential Moving Averages). My results appear to be correct (compared to the calculations I did by hand) so I believe the following method works, but just wanted to get an extra set of eyes to makes sure i'm not missing anything.

Note that this just returns the EMA for the latest price, it doesn't return an array of EMA's as that isn't what I need for my application.

I am using this link as a reference: [Exponential Moving Average](http://fxtrade.oanda.com/learn/forex-indicators/exponential-moving-average)

```
class Indicators:

    def sma(self, data, window):
        """
        Calculates Simple Moving Average
        http://fxtrade.oanda.com/learn/forex-indicators/simple-moving-average
        """
        if len(data) < window:
            return None
        return sum(data[-window:]) / float(window)

    def ema(self, data, window, position=None, previous_ema=None):
        """
        Calculates Exponential Moving Average
        http://fxtrade.oanda.com/learn/forex-indicators/exponential-moving-average
        """
        if len(data) < window + 2:
            return None
        c = 2 / float(window + 1)
        if not previous_ema:
            return self.ema(data, window, window, self.sma(data[-window*2 + 1:-window + 1], window))
        else:
            current_ema = (c * data[-position]) + ((1 - c) * previous_ema)
            if position > 0:
                return self.ema(data, window, position - 1, current_ema)
            return previous_ema


# Sample close prices for GBP_USD currency pair on the 2 hour timeframe
close_prices = [1.682555, 1.682545, 1.682535, 1.682655, 1.682455, 1.682685, 1.68205, 1.683245, 1.68405, 1.68401, 1.68506, 1.685825, 1.685955, 1.686595, 1.686325, 1.686375, 1.68701, 1.684995, 1.687245, 1.686135, 1.686205, 1.68724, 1.68753, 1.687775, 1.688245, 1.687745, 1.68699, 1.687285, 1.686325, 1.686295, 1.683945, 1.683035, 1.68401, 1.68327, 1.685185, 1.684755, 1.685265, 1.685325, 1.68625, 1.685645, 1.684355, 1.68387, 1.68413, 1.68416, 1.683425, 1.68481, 1.683245, 1.683645, 1.68325, 1.682745, 1.680385, 1.680655, 1.680875, 1.679995, 1.680445, 1.68064, 1.67937, 1.677735, 1.67769, 1.67777, 1.677525, 1.677435, 1.67766, 1.677835, 1.678005, 1.67823, 1.67902, 1.678605, 1.678425, 1.67876, 1.678555, 1.678505, 1.679085, 1.678755, 1.678125, 1.677495, 1.67677, 1.676205, 1.67716, 1.67741, 1.677135, 1.679295, 1.68054, 1.68143, 1.68115, 1.68111, 1.68055, 1.680495, 1.680565, 1.681375, 1.68244, 1.673395, 1.670885, 1.67156, 1.669525, 1.66906, 1.66903, 1.668935, 1.668805, 1.667895, 1.667905, 1.668485, 1.666345, 1.66832, 1.668005, 1.668615, 1.669305, 1.668415, 1.66891, 1.66843, 1.66855, 1.66834, 1.668725, 1.66952, 1.668075, 1.66859, 1.669, 1.669685, 1.668575, 1.66909, 1.66957, 1.669375, 1.671655, 1.67186, 1.67244, 1.6729, 1.672965, 1.673405, 1.67284, 1.67256, 1.67216, 1.67193, 1.673265, 1.67295, 1.672705, 1.67224, 1.67221, 1.67222, 1.67254, 1.670105, 1.66501, 1.663845, 1.66201, 1.661935, 1.661725, 1.66189, 1.661605, 1.661925, 1.66215, 1.66049, 1.660185, 1.66233, 1.66374, 1.66491, 1.665195, 1.663225, 1.66267, 1.65927, 1.659415, 1.65998, 1.6583, 1.656825, 1.65741, 1.659025, 1.658355, 1.659355, 1.65871, 1.65887, 1.658595, 1.65768, 1.657965, 1.657855, 1.657415, 1.658125, 1.65816, 1.659125, 1.658245, 1.65773, 1.658585, 1.65732, 1.657825, 1.65731, 1.65725, 1.65433, 1.654875, 1.65508, 1.656205, 1.656185, 1.6567, 1.658865, 1.658805, 1.65879, 1.6584, 1.65806, 1.658145, 1.65706, 1.656925, 1.65885, 1.65917, 1.659, 1.65794, 1.65797, 1.65711, 1.658675, 1.656915, 1.65474, 1.65455, 1.654135, 1.65467, 1.65473, 1.65543, 1.65465, 1.65721, 1.65717, 1.65927, 1.65895, 1.65724, 1.65812, 1.657435, 1.657395, 1.65755, 1.65975, 1.65983, 1.658975, 1.658855, 1.65814, 1.65838, 1.65797, 1.65785, 1.657795, 1.658915, 1.65888, 1.65888, 1.65869, 1.65851, 1.658195, 1.659985, 1.65933, 1.65842, 1.65836, 1.658435, 1.657605, 1.660225, 1.65991, 1.65908, 1.659065, 1.659605, 1.659555, 1.660535, 1.663025, 1.662295, 1.661525, 1.662735, 1.661335, 1.660895, 1.660905, 1.66093, 1.661425, 1.65934, 1.658235, 1.658305, 1.657035, 1.652785, 1.653185, 1.65176, 1.650105, 1.648505, 1.64713, 1.646975, 1.646815, 1.646575, 1.645355, 1.646425, 1.646365, 1.648295, 1.646245, 1.646305, 1.645075, 1.644875, 1.646035, 1.64602, 1.646025, 1.645615, 1.646135, 1.645585, 1.645695, 1.646195, 1.642865, 1.64237, 1.634805, 1.634575, 1.634475, 1.631665, 1.629265, 1.631115, 1.63094, 1.631775, 1.632175, 1.631775, 1.629345, 1.632785, 1.631155, 1.631765, 1.632865, 1.6327, 1.618735, 1.621365, 1.622655, 1.620755, 1.617995, 1.616985, 1.611595, 1.61411, 1.615785, 1.613975, 1.611155, 1.610865, 1.60935, 1.609255, 1.610085, 1.607585, 1.608405, 1.610095, 1.611495, 1.610465, 1.609775, 1.608715, 1.608615, 1.612435, 1.610495, 1.612275, 1.612555, 1.611785, 1.612515, 1.612945, 1.609495, 1.612515, 1.616155, 1.613295, 1.618215, 1.621225, 1.62018, 1.619885, 1.619565, 1.620435, 1.619375, 1.624325, 1.625165, 1.625185, 1.621845, 1.622345, 1.623795, 1.621875, 1.627455, 1.624845, 1.623875, 1.623625, 1.623295, 1.625575, 1.626125, 1.622445, 1.622145, 1.624155, 1.626055, 1.625755, 1.62671, 1.627055, 1.625875, 1.625055, 1.623925, 1.624645, 1.625215, 1.624725, 1.624025, 1.624515, 1.624205, 1.623755, 1.623325, 1.62273, 1.622535, 1.6242, 1.623045, 1.62169, 1.618415, 1.618185, 1.619605, 1.621425, 1.627035, 1.628145, 1.62778, 1.6271, 1.626485, 1.626335, 1.627615, 1.627965, 1.63094, 1.630125, 1.632065, 1.633775, 1.632895, 1.63064, 1.627885, 1.625845, 1.62667, 1.626805, 1.626695, 1.631185, 1.629635, 1.63067, 1.63367, 1.63908, 1.63709, 1.637255, 1.63738, 1.64403, 1.642545, 1.650745, 1.65183, 1.64764, 1.646825, 1.639945, 1.634085, 1.633615, 1.631255, 1.63123, 1.62993, 1.628745, 1.629105, 1.63096, 1.63417, 1.635245, 1.634745, 1.633755, 1.63316, 1.633325, 1.63464, 1.63394, 1.635555, 1.636435, 1.636235, 1.63692, 1.638125, 1.63869, 1.637795, 1.6323, 1.638925, 1.640955, 1.63767, 1.63686, 1.636575, 1.63977, 1.63909, 1.63945, 1.64001, 1.641005, 1.63986, 1.63838, 1.64039, 1.64047, 1.636, 1.63434, 1.634115, 1.633895, 1.633725, 1.63255, 1.633225, 1.63228, 1.632915, 1.63046, 1.630275, 1.628565, 1.63377, 1.631165, 1.630405, 1.63149, 1.63178, 1.63308, 1.63234, 1.630675, 1.630235, 1.63027, 1.632255, 1.630505, 1.626665, 1.625325, 1.624565, 1.624355, 1.62497, 1.62389, 1.62394, 1.62399, 1.622855, 1.621865, 1.62358, 1.62292, 1.623685, 1.624135, 1.62672, 1.624515, 1.624305, 1.624215, 1.62416, 1.623665, 1.6259, 1.625805, 1.626625, 1.62005, 1.618425, 1.62162, 1.62192, 1.620865, 1.62121, 1.621525, 1.621475, 1.619475, 1.619145, 1.619835, 1.620235, 1.6204, 1.618875, 1.622535, 1.62144, 1.617695, 1.61798, 1.61831, 1.618825, 1.61982, 1.62336, 1.621535, 1.61987, 1.616985, 1.6134, 1.61441, 1.6139, 1.61428, 1.61376, 1.61498, 1.615715, 1.612955, 1.61323, 1.61406, 1.6102, 1.606695, 1.60757, 1.59774, 1.59611, 1.597425, 1.597505, 1.59687, 1.59683, 1.596235, 1.59762, 1.59792, 1.59878, 1.596685, 1.598745, 1.59928, 1.60067, 1.602755, 1.603465, 1.607645, 1.608225, 1.60736, 1.60442, 1.604255, 1.60657, 1.60907, 1.604735, 1.607615, 1.61128, 1.607135, 1.60798, 1.60935, 1.60968, 1.60865, 1.607105, 1.60607, 1.606545, 1.60638, 1.607575, 1.60701, 1.60822, 1.606605, 1.604175, 1.617025, 1.615945, 1.616205, 1.61726, 1.61868, 1.618035, 1.62082, 1.620575, 1.62089, 1.61883, 1.61219, 1.61243, 1.61167, 1.61194, 1.61212, 1.61281, 1.61193, 1.61268, 1.606455, 1.60555, 1.60459, 1.60322, 1.604705, 1.60562, 1.606145, 1.6077, 1.60683, 1.60916, 1.611945, 1.61187, 1.611335, 1.60832, 1.609145, 1.60955, 1.608575, 1.60676, 1.606755, 1.60695, 1.607395, 1.606405, 1.6076, 1.606815, 1.60695, 1.604905, 1.59545, 1.59164, 1.59162, 1.592925, 1.59173, 1.590465, 1.590475, 1.588995, 1.58925, 1.590845, 1.590575, 1.589605, 1.59287, 1.59246, 1.597345, 1.596035, 1.591425, 1.59756, 1.60024, 1.59879, 1.600055, 1.598305, 1.597, 1.59925, 1.596045, 1.598845, 1.600635, 1.606405, 1.60702, 1.609275, 1.607365, 1.609575, 1.60851, 1.60739, 1.607985, 1.60689, 1.60864, 1.61119, 1.606205, 1.60851, 1.61039, 1.6088, 1.609185, 1.609595, 1.609035, 1.609775, 1.61074, 1.61063, 1.61041, 1.612855, 1.612635, 1.61363, 1.613635, 1.61695, 1.61705, 1.615905, 1.615515, 1.61577, 1.617205, 1.618045, 1.616225, 1.61466, 1.61568, 1.61528, 1.613335, 1.613045, 1.611435, 1.61178, 1.611265, 1.612395, 1.612615, 1.61215, 1.607975, 1.604285, 1.60507, 1.60358, 1.606845, 1.606225, 1.605045, 1.60427, 1.60436, 1.604135, 1.60491, 1.60554, 1.603425, 1.60145, 1.602715, 1.602035, 1.603575, 1.60334, 1.602125, 1.602895, 1.602555, 1.60353, 1.603785, 1.60398, 1.603185, 1.60395, 1.605205, 1.608145, 1.6097, 1.608285, 1.60858, 1.609015, 1.608575, 1.609035, 1.61034, 1.61067, 1.61045, 1.610075, 1.609925, 1.609565, 1.61126, 1.61328, 1.612295, 1.61265, 1.611675, 1.61242, 1.61272, 1.61275, 1.61212, 1.612105, 1.610675, 1.611365, 1.617255, 1.61567, 1.613815, 1.61384, 1.613175, 1.61411, 1.6132, 1.613675, 1.61394, 1.613675, 1.612405, 1.61159, 1.61244, 1.6149, 1.609405, 1.600625, 1.60129, 1.600285, 1.597765, 1.59804, 1.597085, 1.59792, 1.598775, 1.598545, 1.60051, 1.602205, 1.599575, 1.599565, 1.600345, 1.59987, 1.599305, 1.599525, 1.597605, 1.599295, 1.59902, 1.600385, 1.59634, 1.59984, 1.599365, 1.599665, 1.59966, 1.597265, 1.593855, 1.59653, 1.59713, 1.59792, 1.59974, 1.60036, 1.599825, 1.598095, 1.598495, 1.59798, 1.597485, 1.59773, 1.597355, 1.5986, 1.599495, 1.599755, 1.60003, 1.600025, 1.600375, 1.60105, 1.598955, 1.600155, 1.599765, 1.600475, 1.60022, 1.6006, 1.60181, 1.596045, 1.5943, 1.588815, 1.59068, 1.596245, 1.59832, 1.59755, 1.59771, 1.59605, 1.595625, 1.59563, 1.597925, 1.599085, 1.59813, 1.594745, 1.593165, 1.592695, 1.586095, 1.58439, 1.583355, 1.583495, 1.58396, 1.58395, 1.58188, 1.58351, 1.58259, 1.583445, 1.582, 1.58423, 1.584275, 1.58594, 1.58744, 1.58719, 1.588185, 1.58738, 1.589525, 1.590055, 1.59015, 1.588425, 1.590905, 1.589435, 1.587295, 1.585705, 1.585945, 1.584915, 1.584655, 1.585055, 1.585295, 1.58395, 1.58466, 1.584475, 1.58468, 1.585585, 1.586555, 1.588415, 1.59241, 1.591835, 1.591695, 1.590885, 1.591405, 1.590985, 1.591665, 1.592275, 1.5882, 1.581655, 1.580375, 1.58148, 1.57864, 1.578555, 1.57667, 1.577125, 1.577305, 1.57743, 1.577365, 1.577185, 1.57641, 1.574255, 1.57483, 1.57164, 1.570785, 1.57102, 1.5706, 1.568675, 1.567595, 1.56684, 1.56692, 1.56813, 1.567345, 1.565315, 1.560175, 1.565545, 1.568455, 1.567155, 1.566805, 1.566615, 1.567495, 1.57258, 1.572635, 1.571035, 1.56638, 1.56362, 1.564205, 1.56323, 1.564425, 1.56413, 1.564065, 1.56356, 1.56443, 1.565565, 1.565335, 1.565155, 1.56566, 1.565865, 1.564555, 1.564785, 1.564695, 1.56344, 1.5631, 1.56226, 1.561195, 1.56147, 1.560665, 1.562395, 1.56057, 1.56928, 1.566655, 1.56624, 1.566875, 1.56932, 1.56767, 1.56817, 1.567015, 1.567355, 1.56741, 1.56635, 1.565175, 1.566865, 1.570025, 1.57282, 1.56816, 1.570325, 1.56959, 1.56924, 1.56901, 1.570075, 1.569705, 1.56823, 1.56393, 1.56667, 1.56727, 1.56499, 1.56707, 1.564855, 1.566205, 1.56555, 1.564845, 1.565205, 1.56587, 1.56643, 1.56677, 1.564145, 1.56529, 1.56839, 1.568565, 1.569955, 1.569735, 1.570485, 1.57035, 1.569595, 1.568, 1.567995, 1.568395, 1.56889, 1.567615, 1.56646, 1.57027, 1.57135, 1.57154]
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.SE ! Would you be able to provide dummy data so that one can give your code a try before reviewing it ?

Comment: Hi Josay, I've added a sample list of data for you if you'd like to test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Recursion is a good tool for the right job, but here it is used to accomplish simple looping. As such the code...

  - is more difficult to read and reason about.
  - is slower because much of the code in `ema` only needs to run once.
  - will fail with large enough value of `window` due to overflowing Python's call stack.
- Please document at least the parameters of each function, eg. that `window` is the *length* of the window, and that `position` counts *backwards* from the end of `data`. (In fact things would be clearer if `position` were a normal forward index into `data`)
- Raise an exception when you find a parameter has an invalid value. Returning `None` instead will only cause a more confusing exception later. In fact, if I try `Indicators().ema(close_prices, 600)` I get infinite recursion because `sma` returns `None`, which makes `ema` call `sma` over and over again.
- The previous point also reveals that `if len(data) < window + 2` is not the right validity check.
- The `+ 1` in `data[-window*2 + 1:-window + 1]` don't seem correct to me. I suppose you want `data[-window*2:-window]`
- The statement `return previous_ema` is in an odd place because at that point you have calculated a new `current_ema`. This is the base case of the recursion, and it is customary to handle the base case first.

My proposal for `ema`:

```
def ema(self, data, window):
    if len(data) < 2 * window:
        raise ValueError("data is too short")
    c = 2.0 / (window + 1)
    current_ema = self.sma(data[-window*2:-window], window)
    for value in data[-window:]:
        current_ema = (c * value) + ((1 - c) * current_ema)
    return current_ema
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty shallow review :

You don't need to write a class for what you are doing (and I suggest you have a look at [this video](http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes)). Your class does not encapsulate any data and you just use it to have your functions in a the same entity. I guess things would easier to understand if you were to define `classmethod` to make it obvious that you won't really rely on any instance whatsoever. However, an even better option would be to just define functions in a `indicator` module.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I actually did have them as classmethods and debated going back and forth between even using a class or just defining functions in an indicator module (which I will now do).

Comment: Just watched the video too, great stuff.